# Java string identification

Tags: java, parsing, tree, integer

okay so I have this first class that breaks down a string, strips the spaces and everything, puts it into an Arraylist and feeds it to this parseRec class. For some reason when the first character is "+" it does not register for this first if statement. It surpasses it ang goes to the else statement which is supposed to only take integers. any ideas why?

```
public static Expression parseRec(ArrayList<String> list) {
    while (list.size() != 0) {
        if (list.get(i) == "+") {
            System.out.println("got this far");
                    .....................

        else {
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
            String intE = list.get(i);
            Expression intExp = new IntExpression(intE);
            list.remove(i);
            return intExp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: use String.equals(String)

Answer (score 1):

Compare `String`s with the `equals()` method:

```
if (list.get(i).equals("+")) {
```

instead of:

```
if (list.get(i) == "+") {
```

The `==` compares references and not the string contents. To compare two `String` objects' contents, never use `==`.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite this portion

```
 if (list.get(i) == "+") {
        System.out.println("got this far");
                .....................
```

as

```
 if (list.get(i).equals("+")) {
        System.out.println("got this far");
                .....................
```

Comparison of String should be made by `.equals()` for exact comparison of value.

Comment: I dont see i defined anywhere. It is likely that list.get(i) is undefined and therefore not == "+" then going to the else

Comment: The portion of code having the issue likely is this. @clancer Yes I do agree, i is not defined and it goes to the compilation issue if not defined. Its not about compilation issue.

Answer (score 0):

i would probably do

```
if ("+".equals(list.get(i))
```

to avoid NullPointerException in case list.get(i) is null